# how to assign input values to ruby varible?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I need the selected value inside the data-toggle ="modal". I'm getting the value but unable to assign to ruby variable so I cant fetch the the data what I want.

```
<%= form_for(:repair, :url => { :controller => "owners", :action => 'property_repairs',:owner_id => current_user.owner.slug }) do |f| %>

 <%= collection_select(:property,:id,Property.where(owner_id: @owner.id, property_active: true).order(created_at: :desc),:id,:property_address,{:prompt => 'please select the property for Repair'},{class: "form-control"}) %>

 <%= f.submit 'Repair', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

 <% @repair = Repair.where(:owner_id => @owner.id)%>
<%end%>

<% @repair = Repair.where(:owner_id => @owner.id)%>

  <% @repair.each do |repair| %>      

  <%property = Property.find(repair.property_id)%>

  <tr>
  <td class="input-group-addon "> <%=property.property_address %></td> 
  <td class="input-group-addon"> <%= repair.category %></td> 
  <td class="input-group-addon"> <%= repair.start_date %></td>
  <td class="input-group-addon"> <%= repair.end_date%></td>
  <td class="input-group-addon"> <%= repair.cost %></td>
  <div id="pop">


  <td button type="button" data-id = "<%=repair.id%>" class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myPop">
    <h class="text-primary text-left">View</h>
       </td>
</tr>
  <%end%>
```

I given "modal" in same html.erb. here I want the data which I had selected

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myPop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="modal-body">
     <div>


     <input id = "myPop" value ="">  


    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Inside the script I am getting value but unable assign in Modal because it's coming in input value

```
 <script>

 $(document).on("click", ".input-group-addon", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 var value =    $(".modal-body #myPop").val( myBookId );
 });
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store that value in DB yo should use AJAX to call ruby method. Otherwise you will not be able to assign javascript-var to ruby-var.

Take a look at link_to or form_for with :remote => true option: